# Miss Forest & Iterative PCA : How to handle very sparse matrix imputation?

Tags: pca, random-forest, simulation, missing-data, sparse

I am currently benchmarking matrix completion methods (k-NN, RandomForest and iterative PCA) on multivariate normal data in which I introduce a certain proportion of NA (5 to 95%). My performance criteria here is NRMSE (Normalized Root Mean Square Error).

In order to get an idea of the stability of each method, I create for every {imputation method ; NA percentage} 50 sparse matrix that I impute. I then calculate a standard deviation for NRMSE which I use in my plots.

So I wrote a little R script doing this that gives an output like that one (The data here is a small 150x4 matrix, generated with a Pearson correlation of 0.3 between the variables) :

[image: a busy cat]

As you can see, I also tried mean & median imputation as references.

The reason I am writing here is that I am having a little trouble interpreting my results. I mean :

- Is Random Forest imputation (using MissForest) not suitable at all when sparsity is very high ?
- How do you explain the maximum for iPCA when %NA = 80% ? I used here the imputePCA function from missMDA package.

I did the experiment for a large variety of data (non linear, 10x more rows, 10x more columns, etc) and I am getting some odd results. If you have any ideas or questions I will be very happy to expose my experiment to you.

Thanks !